# Actions Push Notifications 403

Tags: jwt, actions-on-google

I followed the tutorial from https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/notifications. But, I am always getting Forbidden error. I have done the following

1. Enabled Actions API on the project
2. Created service account on the project and granted it Owner role
3. Using the key information from JSON file that I exported

I am not using DialogFlow.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4a0y.png)

Comment: Has the given user opted into using notifications?

Comment: @NickFelker -  Yes. I don't have Account linking enabled as well, because it does not say anything about this in the docs.

Comment: Where do you get the user notification token?

Comment: It is exactly as described the Google tutorial I have linked on the question.

Comment: I was checking the logs and found this additional info: SendToConversation response: WAA-off notifications are disabled or not allowed for interaction type. I have no idea what this means.

Comment: Are notifications enabled for that user account?

Comment: I have enabled Actions API as per documentation (https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/notifications#send_notifications) for the project. How do I enabled notifications for the account? It is just my Gmail account I am using for testing.

Comment: The guide shows how to get the specific user account the prompt for them to enable notifications.

Comment: If you are talking about permission to send push notifications, the user has already granted that. Please see https://twitter.com/RajYRaman/status/1435022497481519107?s=20